# How to change table of content header in knitr?

Tags: r, knitr, tableofcontents

I am using the following options to produce a pdf document with knitr:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Paulo Miramor"
date: "13-07-2015"
output: pdf_document
toc: yes
---
```

I would like to change the header of the table of contents (which is "Contents"), since I am producing a document in Portuguese. Is there any way to customize it?

Comment: You should start with adding `lang: portuguese` to the header. If it works, you're lucky that your TeX installation supports the language. If it fails, then you should try to add this by yourself. I can't give a definitive answer because that's what I'm trying to do right now. In case you're using a debian-based linux, `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-portuguese` might work.

Comment: See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28518/28366

Comment: @Molx and Chris, I posted an answer that is a summary of both comments, both worked for me. I hope you don't mind. If you see any problem, please post an answer and I'll accept as the correct answer and delete mine without any problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @Molx and @Chris in the comments I could find a solution.

**Solution 1**

Add `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice}` to the document so that the `.Rmd` header is:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Paulo Miramor"
date: "13-07-2015"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
   - \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Whatever}
toc: yes
---
```

With this solution the header is `Whatever` you put inside `\contentsname` argument.

**Solution 2**

Add `lang: portuguese` to the document so that the `.Rmd` header is:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Paulo Miramor"
date: "13-07-2015"
output: pdf_document
lang: portuguese
toc: yes
---
```

Using this solution the header was a translation of "Contents" to Portuguese. This should work if your TeX installation supports the language.

Comment: You were luckier than me then! Which TeX installation do you have? Solution1 does work, but 2 is more robust.

Comment: @Molx I'm using pdfTeX (`pdflatex`) - Linux Mint 17. I don't know if it makes any difference, but I have the `babel` package installed, although I am not calling it directly in the `.Rmd` file.

Comment: I think it does, since the error I get is related to `babel`. But these things work much better on Linux, I was trying on Windows but will give a shot on Ubuntu later.

Comment: Actually I just tried on a different PC with TeXWorks (Win 8.1) and it worked nicely, better than the one with other TeX installations.